# Django Models Auto Increment And Decrement

Tags: django, django-models

I am trying in Django Models to save the objects with an Auto Increment and Auto Decrement function.

`models.Autofield(primary_key=True)`

is already taking the functionality for the incrementation.
However, for the decrementation I think i need to define a seperate function. Does somebody have a smart solution?

My use case is for saving Malfunctions on the administration site.
If we have e.g. 7 Malfunctions (M01, M02, M03 .. M07) and we delete M03, the numbering of the malfunctions including M04 and above should decrement. ( --> M01, M02, M03, .. M06)

Answer (score 1):

`primary_key` field is readonly so you will not be able to decrement it.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/models/fields/#primary-key

Extend model with additional field e.g. `malfunction_number` and handle update of all table items manually on every delete.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a field to update every time a model instance is saved, possibly conditionally on other fields, you can do that by subclassing the save method. [See the doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/topics/db/models/#overriding-model-methods). Note that you may have to tell the superclass that the field needs to be saved. *"If you wish to update a field value in the save() method, you may also want to have this field added to the update_fields keyword argument. This will ensure the field is saved when update_fields is specified..."*